# How to correctly extend classes

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

If I am extending a class that has its own protected member variables and methods, then in the subclass (or the class doing the extending, whichever is right), how do I correctly refer to these things?

For example if I have `protected int mInt` in the extended class, do I make another `int mInt` in the subclass and initialize that as well? Or do I always refer to the parent class' fields and methods directly?

I ask because I need to ensure that certain objects have certain fields, so I need them to all extend the same parent class, but I don't know what this means in terms of how to structure the methods in the subclasses. Do I just use `super` all the time or is it a good idea to make "local" copies of all the parent contents as well?

Comment: I meant protected, sorry

Comment: Edited my post, I meant protected.

Comment: When you extend a class, you will get a "copy" of the protected members. You won't have to do anything additional. Try it and you will see.

Comment: If you really want to be "correct", you also want to avoid protected fields as much as possible. They make reasoning about your code very difficult.

Comment: I know I don't "have" to, but I am asking if it's considered good practice to. I can always call super.mInt but I don't know if this "obscures" things because if you look at the subclass, you don't see `mInt` anywhere unless you go look at the parent class, which I don't know if that's considered good or bad

Comment: @biziclop How can I possibly avoid that, though? In my case I am making a function that accepts an object that must have getName() and getSourceData() methods, which means they must have name and data members. Doesn't this imply that I need a base class containing these methods and members as protected, and then subclasses that extend them?

Comment: Best practice is usually to only do the things you have to do and no more.  You should avoid redundancy unless you understand why something must be added.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Right, I assume that extending is literally the same as if I had copy/pasted the contents of the super class and plopped them right into the subclass (changing the names slightly to avoid collisions).

Comment: You simply create an interface that declares `getName()` and `getSourceData()` and your function can accept any object implementing that interface. What fields an object has is its own private matter.

Comment: @biziclop But then doesn't this mean I lose the guarantee that the contents returned by getName() and getSourceData() are well-formed? If I implement getName() and getSourceData() just once (and robustly) in the parent class, I don't have to worry about it, but if I just make an interface, doesn't this mean it'll accept any-old-thing as long as the data types are correct / it matches the signature in the interface?

Comment: I guess the robustness check is something I'd need to do it whatever function is actually accepting the objects, though, so your point is well taken

Comment: @ArukaJ `doesn't this mean it'll accept any-old-thing as long as the data types are correct` Yes, it does. There are two answers to this: firstly, it's the receiving method's job to check its inputs. Secondly, you can also create your own `Name` and a `SourceData`  class, whose constructors will make sure they're constructed correctly. Now your interface will say: `public Name getName()` and you can be certain that wherever that `Name` came from, it is well-formed. This is a very powerful thing, when you think about it.

Comment: Makes sense. So then in what kind of situation should I bother using `extends` with protected fields/methods?

Comment: @ArukaJ Protected methods are fine, they are like public methods with slightly restricted visibility. Protected fields on the other hand are almost never of any use, I can only think of very contrived situations where their use is justified.

Comment: @biziclop If you'd like to compile/summarize your comments into an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Protected methods** are part of the API of the class, their use is similar to public methods, but their visibility is restricted to subclasses, which is sometimes useful.

**Protected fields** on the other hand are almost never a good idea, as they make it impossible for a class to maintain its invariants. Take this example:

```
class Divider {
   protected int divisor;

   public void setDivisor(int divisor) {
       //we need to check the input to make sure our Divider works correctly 
       if (divisor == 0)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("divisor can't be zero");
       this.divisor = divisor;
   }

   public int divide(int number) {
       return number/divisor;
   }
}
```

So far, so good, however along comes another class:

```
class BadDivider extends Divider {
    public void doABadThing() {
        this.divisor = 0;
    }
}
```

Now we're in a bad situation: all the effort to maintain our class invariant (i.e. `divisor != 0`) was ruined by `BadDivider`. Since anyone can extend `Divider`, there's no way to stop this happening. This also tells us when it is sort of okay to use protected fields: when you can guarantee that you control all the classes that can inherit them. This very rarely happens.

So the solution is to keep every field private and make sure that you check the inputs of your methods (and your constructors). This allows you to reason about the internal state of your objects, and guarantee that they're always in a valid state.

Answer (score 0):

I would always use private attributes; not have a setter unless really needed; have an interface if you need to expose a class member.
That being said, you would inherit class members. You can refer super if not accessible from child and you do not need to create another mInt int in  subclass; if you need to set the value in subclass, you have a protected setter in parent and use in subclass/class. I would advise reading Design Patterns and 4 core OO principles. Hope helps.